# How to solve the bug in simulation of Erlang B tele-traffic model?

Tags: matlab, random, simulation

I am trying to simulate Erlang-B model and by using book "Wireless Communications: Principles and Practice" by Rappaport:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
TimeC=60;
holdTimerate=2;
lambda_loop=0;
for lambda1=0.1:0.1:0.9
    lambda_loop=lambda_loop+1;
    for loop_simul=1:1:1000
Total_channels=5;
%Total_users=1000;
%holdTIME=exprnd(holdTimerate);
%INTERarrivalTime=exprnd(lambda1);
r = poissrnd((lambda1)*TimeC);
%r=7;
time_init=0;
for j_loop=1:1:r
    explambda_array(j_loop)=exprnd(lambda1);
    expHOLD_array(j_loop)=exprnd(holdTimerate);
    time_init=explambda_array(j_loop)+time_init;%exact arrival time
    MatrixH_I(j_loop,:)=[time_init, expHOLD_array(j_loop)];%first one is at what time the call arrive, 
    % second is what is the holding time of each call
end
 Min_A= min(explambda_array);
flag_cha=zeros(Total_channels,3);
j_users=0;
j_loop=1;
Arrivals=0;
TotalLost=0;
flagserver1=0;flagserver2=0;flagserver3=0;flagserver4=0;flagserver5=0;
for i_loop=Min_A(1):0.00002:TimeC %this is a timer
i_empty_servers=1;
if((i_loop-0.00002)<MatrixH_I(j_loop,1) && (i_loop+0.00002)>MatrixH_I(j_loop,1))%search for arriavls
Arrivals=Arrivals+1;
server_empty=find(flag_cha(:,1)==0);
if((isempty(server_empty)~=1)) %if the arrivals are there serach for empty servers
%IndicesWithzero=find(server_empty);
flag_cha(server_empty(i_empty_servers),1)=1;
flag_cha(server_empty(i_empty_servers),2)=MatrixH_I(j_loop,1);
flag_cha(server_empty(i_empty_servers),3)=MatrixH_I(j_loop,2);
server_thatis_one=server_empty(i_empty_servers);
server_empty_r=find(flag_cha(:,1)==0);
if(server_thatis_one==1)
    flagserver1=1;
elseif(server_thatis_one==2)
    flagserver2=2;
elseif(server_thatis_one==3)
flagserver3=3;
elseif(server_thatis_one==4)
    flagserver4=4;
else
    flagserver5=5;
end
i_empty_servers=i_empty_servers+1;
else
    TotalLost=TotalLost+1;
end
j_loop=j_loop+1;
end
if(flagserver1~=0)
flag_cha(flagserver1,3)=flag_cha(flagserver1,3)-0.00002;
if(flag_cha(flagserver1,3)<=0)
   flag_cha(flagserver1,:)=zeros; 
end
end
if(flagserver2~=0)
flag_cha(flagserver2,3)=flag_cha(flagserver2,3)-0.00002;
if(flag_cha(flagserver2,3)<=0)
   flag_cha(flagserver2,:)=zeros; 
end
end
if(flagserver3~=0)
flag_cha(flagserver3,3)=flag_cha(flagserver3,3)-0.00002;
if(flag_cha(flagserver3,3)<=0)
   flag_cha(flagserver3,:)=zeros; 
end
end
if(flagserver4~=0)
flag_cha(flagserver4,3)=flag_cha(flagserver4,3)-0.00002;
if(flag_cha(flagserver4,3)<=0)
   flag_cha(flagserver4,:)=zeros; 
end
end
if(flagserver5~=0)
flag_cha(flagserver5,3)=flag_cha(flagserver5,3)-0.00002;
if(flag_cha(flagserver5,3)<=0)
   flag_cha(flagserver5,:)=zeros; 
end
end
if(Arrivals==r)
   break;
end
%flag_cha
end
ProbabilitySimul(loop_simul)=TotalLost/r;
    end
ProbabilityB(lambda_loop)=mean(ProbabilitySimul,"omitnan");
end
lambda_loop=0.1:0.1:0.9;
 hold on;
plot(lambda_loop,1-ProbabilityB,'o')
```

I am using the following expression for the analytical graph:
$Pr[Blocking]=\frac{\frac{A^C}{C!}}{\sum_{k=0}^C\frac{A^k}{k!}}$
The graphs are not matching at all, I am getting:[image]

Algorithm:

1. Use Poisson process to model arrival
2. Random holding time is modeled using exponential distribution
3. Count the number of arrivals
4. Assign a server to every arrival and make server busy using flag bits
5. Start counter and decrease the holding time
6. Once holding time is zero release the server.
7. if no server is empty and a call arrives it is lost as not counted in **Arrivals**
8. Repeat